# Removing the "Categories" field from an Issue Tracking list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

When I create an Issue Tracking list in SharePoint, I am unable to remove the Categories choice field that it adds by default as part of the Issue content type.  I looked in the list definition but I can't find anything explicit about not allowing the column to be deleted.  Does anybody know why the Delete button isn't showing up?  Is there a way to delete this field?

Answer (score 1):

Toni's solution did work, but be careful- this will also remove the category field from EVERY ISSUES TRACKING LIST being used currently and any future ones created.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of time and retaining functionality, I decided to take the less obtrusive approach and renamed the Category Column to "." and made the default dropdown choice ".".  It's barely noticable and quick/easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I have had a similar issue with field in a variety of fields where once the field is added, it is not possible to remove it.

Sometimes it is possible to create code to delete the field, but in most of the situations I have come across we have had to hide the field to prevent it from appearing.

This requires moving to using Powershell and the SharePoint object model to make the changes.

In most of our implementations, we have found it much better to create a custom solution with a custom feature that adds the custom lists and fields using the XML format for doing this. A list template can then be create exactly for what you need.

Doing it this way gives us more control over the result in a repeatable manner.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to: Portal > Site Settings > Site Content Type Gallery > Site Content Type
2. Select Issue Content Type
3. Select Categories
4. Click Remove button on the new page

Worked for me, just tried it.

Comment: This will just remove the site column from the content type.  I don't want to affect the site content type, I'm looking to just remove the column from a single list...or at least understand why I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to delete the categories field from an issue tracking list in SharePoint, but I did find that it is possible to re-purpose it. You can change the pick-list values to whatever you want, including "Active", "Resolved" and "Closed".

It seems ridiculous to re-purpose the category field as the status field, especially since a status field is included in the issue tracking list by default. But you can delete the status field and then use the category field as a status field--which is probably used more often.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if anyone is still viewing this. The options I've taken are:

1. Create a custom list (not issues tracking list).
2. Allow for managment of content types on the list. Then make the column hidden in the list content type.  That way you don't disrupt the site content type. (just the list content type).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on SharePoint 2016 on-prem:

1. I allowed management of content types for the list on my site.
2. Then made the column 'hidden' (from forms). Go to list settings, click on **Issues** content type. Select the column and change it from optional to hidden.

To verify I didn't impact others, I went to another site and added the issues app. The column was still there in its original state.